# AdsSys forget password -- how to reset?

Tags: advantage-database-server

I'm being assigned to maintain an Advantage-based Clipper program. I tried to use Advantage Data Architect program to connect to the database, but failed. I'm thinking the password I got is wrong... maybe the previous maintainer or somebody else changed it... (it worked on the test server but not on the live server).

So I'm just wondering if it's possible to reset the password without reinstall & lose all the data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Advantage website](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.0/server1/advantage_data_dictionary_user_permissions.htm) states:

**ADSSYS**

*"All Advantage data dictionaries contain an administrative user called ADSSYS. This user has permissions to perform any operation or update on the dictionary. Be aware that if the ADSSYS password is lost, it cannot be recovered or reset."*

NOTE: When the ADSSYS account is created, by default the password is blank; so you may first attempt to leave the password blank.

I suggest [contacting Advantage](http://www.sybase.com/contactus/support) and asking them for the resolution; as this situation has likely occurred before (and will occur again).